# Sharepoint 2013 list - how to conditionally colour java script calculated fields in sharepoint list?

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have some script that I've been working on in a `Sharepoint 2013` list, it fundamentally checks some criteria against a list and returns "Pending", "Complete", "Overdue", or "Missing Due Date".

In order to check against the current date, I've used some Java script found online and modified it to work for my list. The only problem is, I'm also trying to color the text:

> Red if the value is 'Overdue'
>
> Green if the value is 'Complete'
>
> Black for all other cases.

The code returns the values correctly and colors 'Complete' values green, but I cannot get the 'Overdue' values to the colour red.

Here is my code:

```
="<div style='text-align:left; color:"

&IF([Completed Date]="",""

&"<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""{"

&"var SPday=new Date();"

&"SPday.setFullYear("&YEAR(DueDate)&","&MONTH(DueDate)-1&","&DAY(DueDate)&");"

&"var Days=Math.round((SPday.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/86400000);"

&"this.parentNode.innerHTML=((Days<0)?'red':'black');"

&"}"""

&"","green")

&"'>"

 

&IF([Completed Date]="",IF(ISBLANK(DueDate),"Missing Due date","<img src='/_layouts/images/blank.gif' onload=""{"

&"var SPday=new Date();"&"SPday.setFullYear("&YEAR(DueDate)&","&MONTH(DueDate)-1&","&DAY(DueDate)&");"

&"var Days=Math.round((SPday.getTime()-new Date().getTime())/86400000);"

&"this.parentNode.innerHTML=((Days<0)?'Overdue':'Pending');"

&"}"">"),"Complete")

&"</div>"
```

Can this be done this way or should I be trying another way?

Answer (score 0):

For such complex logic, you'd better use CSR.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var CustomCtx = {};

    /**
     * Initialization
     */
    function init() {

        CustomCtx.Templates = {};

        CustomCtx.Templates.Fields = {
            // update ChangeCompleted as your filed static name
            'ChangeCompleted': {
                'View': customDisplay
            }
        };

        // Register the custom template
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(CustomCtx);
    }

    /**
     * Rendering template
     */
    function customDisplay(ctx) {
        //your logic here
    }   

    // Run our intiialization
    init();

})();
```

Links for your reference.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/154c3ed9-9e22-4fda-aba2-b7b12cc4a509/changing-text-color-in-sharepoint-based-on-column-value?forum=sharepointdevelopment

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views